# How to get Component-scoped CSS WITHOUT using Single File Components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

Is it possible to get Component-scoped CSS i.e.

```
<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

WITHOUT using Single File Components?

For example, I have a component:

```js
// MyComponent.ts

import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  template: '<h1>Not a Single File Component</h1>'
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {}
```

How can I add style such as:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

but have it scoped to `MyComponent.ts` only?

Since to use this component I would import it as:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
```

which is not a single file component and does not have a `<style scoped>...</style>`

Answer (score -1):

You could do style binding like so:

```
@Component({
  template: '<h1 :style="color: blue;">Not a Single File Component</h1>'
})
```

Alternatively, you could assign the h1 an id and reference the id in the stylesheet specifically.

```
@Component({
  template: '<h1 id="whatever-this-is">Not a Single File Component</h1>'
})

...

<style>
    #whatever-this-is {
        color: blue;
      }
</style>
```